# Active Directory via LDAP SSL - Dev env Vs Tomcat - Grails webapp

Tags: tomcat, grails, ssl, ldap, truststore

We've written our own custom webap using Grails. The web includes a function for changing a user's password within an active directory server. The issue I'm having deals with the password-change function working when the webapp is run from the development environment versus it not working when run as a webapp under a Tomcat server.

Details:
My understanding is that if you are going to change user's passwords via LDAP on AD, you must communicate to the AD server using a secure LDAP connection.

Here's what I did to make it work: 
In my development environment, which is GGTS (using Grails 2.x)... I saw which JVM it uses. My AD admin then gave me a cert, which I imported into that JVM's \lib\security\cacerts file using keystore.exe. I actually imported it into all the \lib\security\cacerts for all the JRE/JDK's on my machine, just to be safe. When I run the webapp from within my GGTS IDE... I can then use the webapp to change a user's AD password, and it works fine. I believe GGTS runs it's own embedded webserver when you run the webapp from within the GGTS, and I believe it's Tomcat, but I'm not sure.

I then use the Grails war command and to make a WAR file from the webapp. I go and deploy it to a stand-alone Tomcat also running on my machine. But when I try the password change function in my webapp, I get this error:

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Which I believe indicates some kind of error with Tomcat finding the cert within the JVM.

I've ready many posts dealing with this issue, but not able to resolve this. Could anyone shed some insight or additional things I should look for?

Additional notes on things I've tried or observed:
I've tried using these parameters to the Tomcat:
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_91\lib\security\cacerts
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
-Djavax.net.debug=ssl

To both control which truststore the tomcat would use, as well as writting SSL related info to a log file.

When I used the trustStore parameter with my own location, I did see that had an effect within the log file... it would change to using the file I specified, as opposed to using the one it was using before (both had the certs imported into them anyway)
Snippet of log file: 
2016-05-04 09:07:15 Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized
trustStore is: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_91\lib\security\cacerts
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore

I would also see that it seems to mention the cert for my AD server twice.. does this matter? 
adding as trusted cert:
1st time: 
  Subject: CN=*.testdomain1.local, DC=testdomain1, DC=local
  Issuer:  CN=*.testdomain1.local, DC=testdomain1, DC=local
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x116305db11e9d28e409e1dce744cf841
  Valid from Mon May 02 20:40:49 UTC 2016 until Sat May 02 20:50:49 UTC 2026
2nd time:
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=*.testdomain1.local, DC=testdomain1, DC=local
  Issuer:  CN=*.testdomain1.local, DC=testdomain1, DC=local
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x116305db11e9d28e409e1dce744cf841
  Valid from Mon May 02 20:40:49 UTC 2016 until Sat May 02 20:50:49 UTC 2026

Once the error occurs, here's additional log info:

%% Initialized:  [Session-2, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
** TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*** Certificate chain

---

%% Invalidated:  [Session-2, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
http-nio-8080-exec-1, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
http-nio-8080-exec-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
http-nio-8080-exec-1, called closeSocket()
http-nio-8080-exec-1, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
http-nio-8080-exec-1, called close()
http-nio-8080-exec-1, called closeInternal(true)

Comment: Did you try using the same JVM from both the dev environment and from Tomcat? Why is the CN in the certificate subject name start with a dot (who issued this certificate? Active Directory?) Is this a self-signed certificate? Have you tried to deploy the war file in any other container (Wildfly or Jetty)?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it led to me figuring out the issue... It had to do with getting the certificates mixed up... The AD admin issued more than one and that led to confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by a mix-up in the self-signed certificates that were issued by the IT/AD admin.